# Trigger jquery function from c# codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm fairly new to asp.net/c# and very new to jQuery so please forgive me if this is a newb question.

I have a jQuery fancybox installed which is defined by:

```
 function pageLoad(sender, args) {  
 $("#ctl00_wpm_ShowProduct_ctl04_TestAddToCart").fancybox({  
    'width' : 600,   
    'height' : 620,  
    'type' : 'iframe'   });      
}
```

When I click the `asp:HyperLink` that renders as `ctl00_wpn_ShowProduct_ctl04_TestAddToCart` everything works (I realize if I move things on the page this could break but I need to make it work before I make it work well).

I have another asp:Button on that page that I want to do some processing and then open the target URL (calendar) in a fancybox.  In the original the click on the link brought fancybox into play and opened the calendar URL.  Now if I remove that, how do I get the same results from the button after it does its half-dozen other tasks?  I won't have a link to which I can tie the jQuery activation.

I know that codebehind is server and jQuery is client, but if it can work from a link it should work from a button.

Comment: just a suggestion, if possible, you should use "ClientIDMode=Static" on your page so that your are not dealing with those crazy asp.net control names. http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx

Comment: Thanks Zach, but our ecommerce store is set up to use 2.0 (ancient, isn't it!).  I sure wish I could get away from the crazy names.

Comment: @3nigma, thanks for fixing my formatting.  I'm learning from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run javascript on postback and:

you are using AJAX you can do this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "myFunction();", true);
```

otherwise you can use this:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ButtonClickScript", "myFunction();", true);
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `ClientID` on the client side.

If you can do it exclusively through the front end, you could do something like this.

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="LaunchTheFancyBox()" ID=""... />

<script>
    function LaunchTheFancyBox(){ 
        $('#<%=myControl.ClientID%>').fancybox({  
            'width' : 600,   
            'height' : 620,  
            'type' : 'iframe'   
        });    
    }
</script>
```

Note: If you need to send it from the server, you need to inject it through an  control.

Here's a post with the same sort of question
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10346901/open-jquery-fancybox-from-codebehind.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your button, use (you'll need to set your parameter values):

```
OnClientClick="pageLoad(sender, args)"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx